# How to use ruby variable for def name?

Tags: ruby

Not sure is that ever possible, but it would be nice to optimize code this way. 
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$name2 = 'name2'

def ('name1'+$name2)
...
end
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you want the name of the function to be dynamic? What is the use case?

Comment: Do not use global variables even in the examples. Also, you don’t want to name methods dynamically until you feel yourself a ruby guru, in 99% of tasks this is not needed.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel I Im already using variable name inside of the function, and want to use the same text for a function name too, to avoid repetition in further development.

Comment: Why do you need variable method names? What do you try to achieve? This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: @spickermann heh, it looks like all my life is an xy problem))) ok, now I see that I need some array solution. but still looking for way to use just "name2" variations for array list, and leave function names inside looks: something+name2

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method), here is an example:

```
>> foo = "bar"
=> "bar"
>> define_method("foo_#{foo}") do
?>   puts "Hello from method"
>> end
=> :foo_bar
>> foo_bar
=> Hello from method
```

Comment: A comment on what `__method__` is would be helpful.

Comment: Use `__callee__` instead of `__method__` unless you perfectly understand what are you doing. `__method__` returns the name of the original `method` for aliases, which is confusing in most cases.

Comment: ...or  `name = "bubba"; eval "def #{name}; 'hi'; end"; bubba #=> 
"hi"`. What's that flashing red light in my rear-view window? Oh, no, it's the `eval` police!

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're under arrest.